# How to access my site using IP Address?

Tags: ip

I would like to know how to access my website using Ip address instead of domain. Like 173.252.100.16 can used to access facebook.

My Website is: www.jijojose.me
Server have multiple websites hosted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a Terminal or CMD and type `ping www.jijojose.me` then press Enter. 
The IP address listed it's the server's IP address.

However You won't be able to access you website this way (e.g. `http://173.252.100.16`) unless:

1. You know the folder where it is located on the server, and your server has `mod_userdir` or similar extension enabled for the web server.
2. The server it's configured to show by default your website when no valid `host` header is specified.

Comment: Thank You for the answer. Will check with godaddy about the mod_userdir extension.

Answer (score 0):

According to your domain lookup you have your site at GoDaddy, and they have faq here :

http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/5232/finding-your-hosting-accounts-ip-address