# How to access my wordpress via IP in shared hosting

Tags: import

[How to access my site using IP Address?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/78425/how-to-access-my-site-using-ip-address)

Answers how to access my wordpress via IP

However, there are many sites hosted on the same IP.

I want to access my wordpress because the domains that's pointing to the wordpress has expired.

Basically I just want an easy way to export all the posts from the wordpress and import it on another wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Hosting provider generallly provides specific url that you can use for your case. Go in your (host) account page to fetch this url.

When you get your url, if you have a basic blog you'll able to use WordPress Importer plugin (link is on the tools Import page). The Export page will manage the creation of a xml file that you should import with the Importer in at the new url.